# Error declaring a Javascript variable in Rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I get an error when declaring a variable in Javascript, and Rails 3.1.
There are no problems whatsoever if I put the following code on my index.html.erb:

```
<div id='show_time_id' style="background-color: #eee">

<script type="text/javascript">
function updateClock ( )
{
var currentTime = new Date ( );

var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ( );
var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes ( );
var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds ( );

.......


// Update the time display
document.getElementById("clock").firstChild.nodeValue = currentTimeString;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        setInterval('updateClock()', 1000 )
    });
</script>
</div>

<div style="width: 10em; text-align: right; margin: 20px auto;">
<span id="clock">&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

However, if I put the code into a assets\javascript\clock.js file, and then put `<%= javascript_include_tag 'clock' %>`   in my index.html.erb file, I get this error in the error console:

> syntax error
>   http://localhost:3000/assets/clock.js?body=1
>   var currentTime = new Date ( );

It's not a very important matter, since I can leave the code in index.html.erb, but still I'd like to know. Any idea why does this happen?

Comment: I think you still need to show *exactly* what you are doing when put it in `clock.js`.

Comment: That's not about the question, but having `document.getElementById("clock").firstChild.nodeValue` when you load all that jquery code seems to be odd

Comment: @Alexander : That's exactly what I am doing, just copy this code to clock.js and then in index.html.erb substitute it for the include tag.

Comment: @fantactuka : I don't quite understand it myself, I got the code from http://www.elated.com/articles/creating-a-javascript-clock/ , but if I try substituting it for document.write(currentTimeString)  it doesn't refresh the clock.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have written function inside script tag in js file... write function alone do not inside the script tags...

Comment: mmm... but I think Javascript functions must be declared within the script tag. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: If we write javascript functions separate js file. they should not be declared in script tag, because we call js file using script tag..